# How to retry the Observable based on its output

Tags: rx-java

Let's says I have an `Observable` which may or may not emit an event, meaning just `onComplete()` is called without `onNext()`. I need to repeat the operation from the `Observable` if no event emitted. How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switchIfEmpty` might help:

```
source.switchIfEmpty(
           Observable.error(new RuntimeException("is empty")))
      .retry()
```

As is bear in mind that an error other than the one thrown above will prompt a retry as well which may not be ideal. In this case I'd suggest using a different `retry` overload:

```
source.switchIfEmpty(
           Observable.error(new EmptyException()))
      .retry((retryNumber, throwable) -> throwable instanceof EmptyException)
```